Branching strategy 2 sprints together with SIT, UAT and master
We're using a Git branching strategy with SIT, UAT and Master branches. We aim to keep newer sprints in SIT and older one in UAT.
For example, let's say Sprint 6 is currently in SIT and Sprint 5 is in UAT. Once Sprint 5 is released to production, we'll move Sprint 6 to UAT and UAT will observe code freeze unless there is a hotfix.
Our challenge lies in handling hotfixes from master/uat to SIT as we have lots of changes in SIT environment and its the newer code.
We need a way to merge hotfixes from UAT/Master into Sprint 6 (SIT) before merging from SIT to UAT. We want to ensure that the newer code in SIT (with hotfixes applied) is moved to UAT as is. The commit history of SIT and UAT should be same after merging. Similarly whatever will goto UAT will go as is to the master with same commit history.
We're looking for suggestions on:

The most suitable Git branching strategy to achieve this workflow.

Specific merging techniques to handle hotfix integration into SIT (newer sprint) before promotion to UAT while considering that SIT will have lots of changes.

Moving the code from SIT to UAT (just after prod release) and then after sprint is tested in UAT, move to master ensuring that branches are completely in sync with same commit history.


